# Tabular : align text in one colum with line in the other

Tags: tables, alignment

I would like to have a table where the text in the first column is aligned with the lines in the rest of the table.

The result I'm expecting is something like this :

```
8 ---------
  | A | B |
9 ---------
  | C | D | 
10---------
```

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `multirow` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2.5}{*}{8}}  \\
\cline{2-3}
\multirow{2.5}{*}{9} & A & B \\
\cline{2-3}
\multirow{2.5}{*}{10} & C & D \\
\cline{2-3}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```